# Receive a message from StatusCode in Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I often write in controllers something like this:

```cs
return StatusCode(204, "Something is not exist");
```

I also have a self-written Middleware:

```cs
public class StatusCodeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public StatusCodeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        await _next(httpContext);
        await HandleStatusCodeAsync(httpContext);
    }

    private Task HandleStatusCodeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        int errorCode = (int)ErrorCodes.UnknownError;
        string message = "Internal error";
        object details = null;

        switch (context.Response.StatusCode)
        {
            case 401:
                errorCode = (int)ErrorCodes.Unauthorized; // ErrorCodes is my enum of error codes :). It doesn't matter.
                message = "Unauthorized";
                break;
            case 415:
                errorCode = (int)ErrorCodes.BadFields;
                message = "Bad JSON";
                break;
        }

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails()
        {
            StatusCode = errorCode,
            Message = message,
            Details = details
        }.ToString());
    }
}
```

And how and where can I get this underlined message from middleware:

[image return StatusCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdQxA.png)

Comment: Wouldn't "not exist" be 404? :)

Comment: It should be in the response stream.

Comment: 204 in no content. It means ENTITY not exist.

Comment: Okay, David, how can I get this string from response strem. I tried, nothing came of it, just exception.

Comment: Actually, @AlexGrozniy, a 204 means that the target does exist, it just has no content to deliver, so the action actually succeeds. A 404 is the lack of the target (or entity) entirely. Your overriding message could be confusing to users. [Check out Mozillas documentation on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204). You will notice a grouping of status codes, where the 200 range is success indifferent ways and 400 range are failures.

Comment: @AlienFromCA, i'm talking about it

Comment: I'm not talking about a nonexistent route, but about a nonexistent entity by the RIGHT route